# How to avoid Python Subprocess stopping execution

Tags: python, jar, os.system

I have a python program that process a lot of files, and one step is made through a .JAR file
I currently have something like that

```
    for row in rows:
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(f'java -jar ffdec/ffdec.jar -export png "{out_dir}/" "{row[0]}.swf", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        except (OSError, subprocess.SubprocessError, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            print(f"Error on {row[0]}")
            continue
```

That works fine for executing the os command (i'm on Windows 10) and not stop on errors.
However, there is one specific error that stop the execution of my python programm.
I think it is because the .jar file doesn't really stop, and still run in the background, thus preventing python from continuing.

I there a way to call a command in Python and run it asynchronously, or skip it after a timeout of 20sec ?
I can also make a Java program to run that part of the process, but for convenience issue I'll prefer having all on Python

Just in case, i'll put here the error that stops my program (all other get properly caught by try: except:)

```
f�vr. 25, 2021 8:05:00 AM com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.console.ConsoleAbortRetryIgnoreHandler handle
GRAVE: Error occured
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.exporters.commonshape.SVGExporter.addUse(SVGExporter.java:230)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.timeline.Timeline.toSVG(Timeline.java:1043)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.exporters.FrameExporter.lambda$exportFrames$0(FrameExporter.java:216)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.RetryTask.run(RetryTask.java:41)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.exporters.FrameExporter.exportFrames(FrameExporter.java:220)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.console.CommandLineArgumentParser.parseExport(CommandLineArgumentParser.java:2298)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.console.CommandLineArgumentParser.parseArguments(CommandLineArgumentParser.java:891)
    at com.jpexs.decompiler.flash.gui.Main.main(Main.java:1972)
```

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, `check_call()` waits for the process to end, while `Popen()` does not. I recommend you looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking in depth subprocess documentation, I found a parameter called timeout :

```
subprocess.check_call('...', stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, timeout=20)
```

That can do the job for me

[Documentation for timeout](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)